# SOAP abstraction through classes not working properly?

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

Original SOAP contract in WCF (I ommited DTO attributes purposely for readablility):

```
public class A : B
{
    public int Field1 {get;set;}

    public int Field2 {get;set;}
}

public abstract class B 
{
    public int Field3 {get;set;}
}
```

After some time this original contract goes to clients, they use it. Everyone happy. But then I decide to move one field to abstraction level:

```
public class A : B
{
    public int Field2 {get;set;}
}

public abstract class B 
{        
    public int Field1 {get;set;}//heh, become abstract

    public int Field3 {get;set;}
}
```

So, basically, it is the same if this field were just added to every concrete class, whereas for A nothing changes, BUT this breaks old clients.

Why is it so? How to achieve REST flexebility in SOAP, where you can just add field/move it from concrete class to abstraction and everything works?

Answer (score 0):

wcf serializes and deserializes data in proper order.
The order is first property of abstract class and then child class.
So order of your original DataContact is Field3->1, Field1->2,Field2->3.

Then you move the Field1 to your abstract class, so the order will be Field1->1,Field3->2,Field2->3.

After changing , the order of properties of client side and server side doesn't match. So you should change order of your abstract class.

```
 [DataContract]
public abstract class Parent
{
   // IsRequired is used to test whether has received the property

 // if not, it will show error. Order could change the order of the property in message 
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true,Order =1)]
    public int Field3 { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true,Order =2)]
    public int Field1 { get; set; }

}
```

I know this way could only apply to small change , if you want change a lot , please consider using DataContractSurrogate
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/data-contract-surrogates

Comment: This is very sad if it is only solution. SOAP is highly overcomplexed, considering that order in classes doesn't matter at all when you use WCF.

Comment: Another solutions is  DataContractSurrogate, but I am not sure how it satisfies your requirement